# Pandas - How to define the condition of all columns with the same datatype

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Input:

```
**A(Object)   B(Float)C(Object)   D(Float)**

A1            NaN     String1     NaN
B1            2.0     NaN         3.0
C1            NaN     String2     NaN
D1            1.0     String3     2.0
E1            NaN     String4     3.0
F1            2.0     String5     NaN
```

Expected Output:

```
**A(Object)   B(Float)C(Object)   D(Float)**

B1            2.0     NaN         3.0
D1            1.0     String3     2.0
E1            NaN     String4     3.0
F1            2.0     String5     NaN
```

I'm trying to use the code:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include='number').notna().all(axis=1)]
```

but it also removes those rows where only one numeric column is NaN, such as E1.

How to resolt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a slightly different approach with `dropna` rather than `.notna()` and first specify the float columns, which you can pass to the `subset` parameter in `dropna()` and then pass `how=all`:

```
float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns
df = df.dropna(subset=float_cols, how='all')
df
Out[1]: 
    A    B        C    D
1  B1  2.0  NaN      3.0
3  D1  1.0  String3  2.0
4  E1  NaN  String4  3.0
5  F1  2.0  String5  NaN
```